# Is this structure prep+prep right?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I saw this sentence:

> The answer is almost certainly in between.

Here *in* is prep, and *between* is prep, so in grammar can I use prep+prep in general and it's right?

for example can I say:

> I get it at during.

Comment: You can certainly say *I got it **at** Harrods **during** the January sales*. It's not so easy to come up with a context where ***at*** and ***during*** can occur consecutively with no intervening terms, but they do exist: *I don't know what the guest speaker was getting **at during** his after-dinner speech*.

Comment: I've CV'd because I think that even a cursory search will show that "in between" is not usually understood as two prepositions, as OP claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence:

> The answer is almost certainly in between.

is grammatically valid, but it only makes sene if it fits the previous context, particularly if that context specifies two points or answers and suggests choosing between them, or something more or less similar.

However this does not mean that all sequences where one preposition follows another re valis.As with so many things in English, it depends.

"In between" is a very common usage, perhaps it might even be called a fixed phrase. This makes it usable when similar construction might not be.

The suggested example:

> I get it at during.

makes no sense that I can see, and I do not see how it can be considered grammatically valid.

Prepositions most often precede a noun or noun phrase, indicating the direction, location, or time, ot serving to connect the noun or NP to the rest of the sentence. It is less common to see two prepositions used in immediate sequence. Bit in some cases such a use is possible. Fot example:

> I went aboard, despite my misgivings.

Both :*aboard*" and  "*despite*" are usually thought of as prepositions, although it might be argued if they are functioning as such in this example.

> He came in at me, before I could catch my breath.

Here one might argue that "come in" forms a phrasal verb, so "in" is not really functioning as a preposition, although it often does.

In short, it is unusual, but not impossibly, for two preposition to appear together in immediate sequence.

See [Everything You Need To Know About Prepositions](https://www.itepexam.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-prepositions/) for more detail on prepositions.

Comment: *This is the pew I sat **down at during** the vicar's sermon*. You can almost always contrive a syntactically valid context for 2-3 consecutive prepositions, just as you can make any consecutive 2-3 notes work in a melody.

Comment: @FumbleFingers
 Quite true, but here again one might argue that ***sat down*** or even ***sat down at*** functions as a verb, and only ***during*** really functions as a preposition here

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use two prepositions together with no objects.

"In between" is [a single adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20between) that happens to use two words in its spelling.